# How do update an EC2 autoscaled instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've been playing around with EC2 Autoscaling but was wondering how do I make changes to these instances once launched? Do I need to create a new AMI then re-launch everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Puppet or Chef to rapidly change production settings and then rotate the AMIs from time to time to keep AMIs updated so your configuration management app does not need to apply too much changes on startup.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like the way to go. I knew there had to be an easier way :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what types of updates you are trying to do.

1. Setting up a new AMI is certainly one way to go. I do this when i need to make changes to the system configuration.
2. Use some type of automated release process or tools. There are a lot of ways to do do this and it will likely depend on your application. But you can set up a process which would update your application or other system configuration as needed without relaunching a new AMI.